# How do I ping a FastCGI server?

Tags: fastcgi

How do I check if a FastCGI server is alive and running normally beyond just making a TCP connection?

I have a number of remote, stand-alone FastCGI servers.  I want to monitor the FastCGI server itself to ensure its alive.  Simply making a request of the web server is not enough as it will automatically route around a dead server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cgi-fcgi program that comes with [FastCGI development kit](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/).  On Debian-like systems, and in macports, program is included with libfcgi package.

My script with cgi-fcgi invocation is published at http://gist.github.com/209446

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to FastCGI server and send control `FCGI_GET_VALUES` empty request. It should be supported by fastcgi server, the official libfcgi should support it.

See http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fcgi-spec.html

Send to Socket following:

```
unsigned char buf[16] = { 1,9,0,0 ,0,0,8,0 , 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0};
// fcgi protocols = 1
// fcgi_get_values = 9
// padding  = 8 -- for some reason libfcgi expects non-empty body
// body -- empty 8 bytes.
```

You should get

```
unsigned char buf[8] = { 1, 10,0,0, 0,0,0,0 };
// fcgi_protocol = 1
// fcgi_get_values_response = 10
```

You should actually chek you get 10 as response.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  Is there a library I can use to speak to a FastCGI server rather than coding up something to speak a binary protocol?  C, PHP, Ruby or Perl preferred but I'll take anything.

Comment: Added simple example how to implement

Comment: The protocol sequence above could also be implemented in shell: `printf "\1\11\0\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0" | nc -v -o /tmp/log localhost 9000; cat /tmp/log`. Expected received bytes would be `> 00000000 01 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00`.