# How do I get killed using Perl FCGI?

Tags: perl, nginx, ping, fastcgi

I'm having a little problem with nginx and the Perl FCGI module. I have a long operation in my FCGI program that may outlive the server (or the user on the server) on the other end of the Unix socket I'm using to communicate FCGI. I need the FCGI accept() loop in my program to break if the FCGI request is closed. I tried installing INT, TERM, etc signal handlers, but they do nothing, since the only communication between nginx and my program happens over the FCGI socket, AFAIK.

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302209/how-do-i-ping-a-fastcgi-server) but there's no way that I can see to use the FCGI module in Perl to send raw data to or from nginx over the FCGI socket. Is there a way I can do it without modifying the FCGI module to have a "ping" function?

The basic problem is that my program does not know if nginx has terminated the FCGI request.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use FCGI;

my $fcgi_socket = FCGI::OpenSocket( '/tmp/test.socket', 100000 );
my $request = FCGI::Request(\*STDIN, \*STDOUT, \*STDERR, \%ENV, $fcgi_socket);
REQUEST: while($request->Accept() >= 0) {
    #begin handling request
    my $result = '';
    while (1) { #or select(), etc
        if (somehow check whether the fcgi $request is still live) {
            next REQUEST;
        }
        #check for results, set $result if done
    }
    print $result;
}
```

Comment: are there any hitmen out looking for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a `FCGI` implementation which **treats `FCGI_ABORT_REQUEST`**.

You **cannot** use the following, because they ignore `FCGI_ABORT_REQUEST`:

- [FCGI <=v0.69](http://search.cpan.org/~mstrout/FCGI-0.69/) (the one which you are currently using?)
- [FCGI-Async <=v0.19](http://search.cpan.org/~pevans/FCGI-Async-0.19/)
- [Net-FastCGI <=v0.08](http://search.cpan.org/~chansen/Net-FastCGI-0.08/)
- [FCGI-EV <=1.0.7](http://search.cpan.org/~powerman/FCGI-EV-1.0.7/)

You **could use** the following, which **treat `FCGI_ABORT_REQUEST`**:

- [Vitaly Kramskikh's AnyEvent-FCGI](http://search.cpan.org/~vkramskih/AnyEvent-FCGI-0.03/)

When using `AnyEvent-FCGI`, checking for an aborted request is as easy as calling `$request->is_active()`, but keep in mind that `is_active()` will not reflect the true state of the request until the `on_request` handler returns, which means you have to return from `on_request` as soon as possible and somehow do the actual work "in parallel" (you probably don't want to use [Perl threads](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html), but something more akin to [continuations](http://continuity.tlt42.org/)) in order to give the `AnyEvent` loop the opportunity to process any further requests (including `FCGI_ABORT_REQUEST`s) while you are completing the long-winded operations.

I am not familiar enough with `AnyEvent` to know for sure whether there is a better way of doing this, but here's my take, below, for a start:

```
use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::FCGI;

my @jobs;
my $process_jobs_watcher;

sub process_jobs {
  # cancel aborted jobs
  @jobs = grep {
    if ($_->[0]->is_active) {
      true
    } else {
      # perform any job cleanup
      false
    }
  } @jobs;
  # any jobs left?
  if (scalar(@jobs)) {
    my $job = $jobs[0];
    my ( $job_request, $job_state ) = @$job;
    # process another chunk of $job
    #  if job is done, remove (shift) from @jobs
  } else {
    # all jobs done; go to sleep until next job request
    undef $process_jobs_watcher;
  }
}

my $fcgi = new AnyEvent::FCGI(
  port => 9000,
  on_request => sub {
    my $request = shift;
    if (scalar(@jobs) < 5) { # set your own limit
      # accept request and send back headers, HTTP status etc.
      $request.print_stdout("Content-Type: text/plain\nStatus: 200 OK\n\n");
      # This will hold your job state; can also use Continutiy
      #  http://continuity.tlt42.org/
      my $job_state = ...;
      # Enqueue job for parallel processing:
      push @jobs, [ $request, $job_state ];
      if (!$process_jobs_watcher) {
        # If and only if AnyEvent->idle() does not work,
        #  use AnyEvent->timer() and renew from process_jobs
        $process_jobs_watcher = AnyEvent->idle(cb => \&process_jobs);
      }
    } else {
      # refuse request
      $request.print_stdout("Content-Type: text/plain\nStatus: 503 Service Unavailable\n\nBusy!");
    }
  }
);

AnyEvent->loop;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I ended up opening a socket and implementing the FCGI protocol myself. I used IO::Select to check for data to be read from nginx and if the connection closes to terminate the FCGI process the parent process had forked. What's interesting is that in implementing nginx's use of the protocol, I never saw FCGI_ABORT_REQUEST - the connection from nginx just closes if the client closes the connection to nginx. At any rate, I was surprised to see these FCGI modules like AnyEvent::FCGI. I guess need to become better at searching CPAN.